# Login on server fails with OpenVPN client

Tags: windows, networking, openvpn

I was able to setup a new OpenVPN Server behind a Fritz!Box.
I forwarded the Port 1134 to an internal Windows Server 2019.
The local NIC is 192.168.2.9 for the forwarding

There is currently no firewall enabled. The Windows Firewall have an incoming rule for Port 1134, but I disabled the firewalls completely.

The last lines in the server log are:

```
2022-08-02 14:06:10 us=296000 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1621 D:1450 EF:121 EB:406 ET:0 EL:3 ]
2022-08-02 14:06:10 us=296000 Could not determine IPv4/IPv6 protocol. Using AF_INET
2022-08-02 14:06:10 us=296000 Socket Buffers: R=[131072->131072] S=[131072->131072]
2022-08-02 14:06:10 us=296000 UDPv4 link local (bound): [AF_INET]192.168.2.9:1194
2022-08-02 14:06:10 us=296000 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_UNSPEC]
2022-08-02 14:06:10 us=296000 MULTI: multi_init called, r=256 v=256
2022-08-02 14:06:10 us=296000 IFCONFIG POOL IPv4: base=10.19.15.4 size=62
2022-08-02 14:06:10 us=296000 IFCONFIG POOL LIST
2022-08-02 14:06:10 us=296000 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

I setup a test client too. Trying to connect shows this log entries.

```
2022-08-02 14:50:46 us=46000 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1557,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-client'
2022-08-02 14:50:46 us=46000 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tun,link-mtu 1557,tun-mtu 1500,proto UDPv4,cipher AES-256-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 256,key-method 2,tls-server'
2022-08-02 14:50:46 us=46000 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]a.b.c.d:1194
2022-08-02 14:50:46 us=46000 Socket Buffers: R=[65536->65536] S=[65536->65536]
2022-08-02 14:50:46 us=46000 UDP link local: (not bound)
2022-08-02 14:50:46 us=46000 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]a.b.c.d:1194
2022-08-02 14:50:46 us=46000 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1659444646,WAIT,,,,,,
2022-08-02 14:50:46 us=46000 UDP WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]a.b.c.d:1194: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
2022-08-02 14:50:46 us=46000 UDP READ [0] from [AF_UNSPEC]: DATA UNDEF len=-1
2022-08-02 14:50:48 us=78000 UDP WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]a.b.c.d:1194: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
2022-08-02 14:50:52 us=140000 UDP WRITE [14] to [AF_INET]a.b.c.d:1194: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2 kid=0 [ ] pid=0 DATA len=0
```

I can't see any reactions on the server.
But I can see in WireShark that this message arrives:

```
7588 22.010684 d.e.f.g 192.168.2.9 OpenVPN 60 MessageType: P_CONTROL_HARD_RESET_CLIENT_V2
```

It is easy for me to monitor the traffic because all IPs are static.
I already set "verb 6" on the server and the client.

Switching from UDP to TCP doesn't change anything.

What else can I search for?
Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is a different one.

I have a Windows RRAS server running on the same machine.

And this seams to conflict. I thought that there are different ports in use on inbound. But RRAs seams to capture all the traffic from OpenVPN.

I will start a new question: How to get OpenVPN plus RRAS on the same machine.